# Como verificar se JSON tem essa estrutura?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu tenho um arquivo json que varia sua estrutura

```
{
    "Plan1": [
        {
            "Sequencia": "1",
            "Mês de aniversario": "agosto",
            "Nome Completo": "Joao da silva"
         }
     ]
}
```

e queria verificar se esses indices tem esses valores?
qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso com jquery?

Eu quero verificar se o json tem essa estrutura sempre, entao os indices tem q ser essses
Sequencia
Mês de aniversario
Nome Completo

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Não consegui compreender o tipo de variação a que você se refere. O problema é apenas a posição dos dados no vetor?

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer o que precisas fazer? podes dar mais exemplos do que pretendes e de como os dados podem aparecer?

Comment: alterei pra que fique mais claro @Sergio eu preciso que o json tenha essa estrutura

Comment: @GuilhermeFreire, se você quer validar a estrutura de um `JSON`, deve montar um [`JSON Schema`](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) para tal, uma boa implementação para JavaScript é o [`JJV JSON Validator`](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv)... aqui está um fiddle com um exemplo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/uonp7npj/)

Comment: @GuilhermeFreire e o que queres fazer se um dos JSONs não tiver essa estrutura? tirá-lo da array, completá-lo ou registar o erro?

Comment: @Sergio acho que o schema vai funcionar, eu quero que me de um erro se o json não tiver essa estrutura

Comment: @GuilhermeFreire nesse caso é algo como isto que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/ksj8tydd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guilherme, se deseja validar a estrutura de um JSON, te aconselho a montar um `JSON Schema` para o mesmo, você pode ler mais a respeito em: [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org)

No site acima possui uma lista de bibliotecas para realizar a validação do JSON, no caso do JavaScript, eu recomendo uma das três abaixo:

1. [JJV: JJV JSON Validator](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv)
2. [z-schema validator](https://github.com/zaggino/z-schema)
3. [Ajv: Another JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

para validar o JSON que informou da pergunta, você pode usar o seguinte Schema:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    'Plan1': {
      'type': 'array',
      'minItems': 1,
      'items':  {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          'Sequencia': {
            type: 'number'
          },
          'Mês de aniversario': {
            type: 'string',
            enum: [
              'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 
              'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro'
            ]
          },
          'Nome Completo': {
            type: 'string'
          }
        },
        required: ['Sequencia', 'Mês de aniversario', 'Nome Completo']
      }
    }
  },
  required: ['Plan1']
}
```

Note que no caso acima todas as propriedades são obrigatorias e o Sequencial deve ser numerico.

abaixo segue um exemplo de implementação usando o `AJV`

```js
var schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    'Plan1': {
      'type': 'array',
      'minItems': 1,
      'items':  {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          'Sequencia': {
            type: 'number'
          },
          'Mês de aniversario': {
            type: 'string',
            enum: [
              'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 
              'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro'
            ]
          },
          'Nome Completo': {
            type: 'string'
          }
        },
        required: ['Sequencia', 'Mês de aniversario', 'Nome Completo']
      }
    }
  },
  required: ['Plan1']
};

var json1 = {
  "Plan1": [
    {
      "Sequencia": 1,
      "Mês de aniversario": "agosto",
      "Nome Completo": "Joao da silva"
    }
  ]
}

var json2 = {
  "Plan1": [
    {
      "Sequencia": "2",
      "Mês de aniversario": "13º mês",
      "Nome Completo": "Joao da silva"
    }
  ]
}


var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

if (validate(json1)) 
  console.log("json valido!");
else {
  console.log("json invalido: " + JSON.stringify(validate.errors));
}

if (validate(json2)) 
  console.log("json valido!");
else {
  console.log("json invalido: " + JSON.stringify(validate.errors));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/4.0.5/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado